# How to fetch all apps running across Orgs?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Using `cf cli`, I can login with a specific org (as option) and get the list of apps across spaces in that specific org.

```
cf login --skip-ssl-validation -a <URL> -u <user_name> -p <password> -o <org_name> -s <space>
```

Org names can be increasing/decreasing, as multiple users access app manager

1. How can a user manually get list of all Running apps (and its details) across orgs? Does Cloud Foundry provide any API?
2. After retrieving list of all apps across users for one time initially, we then read log messages from Doppler URL, to watch `Staging complete` events for any app from our program continuously, to get the new app details. How to access Doppler URL? Using `wss` or `https`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to list Orgs and Spaces in Cloud Foundry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487792/need-to-list-orgs-and-spaces-in-cloud-foundry)

Comment: @jonrsharpe query edited..

Comment: You just made it broader. Please read [ask], and https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After acquiring active token (cf login...), you can use cf curl for consuming cf [api](http://v3-apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/version/3.68.0/index.html)

So, for your case, a good starting point would be calling apps api.

```
cf curl "v3/apps"
```

But, it's only start as you will have to filter manually apps in state **STARTED**
and don't forget is cf api is returning data by chunks, so you will also have to paginate over all results.

Comment: As you are saying `cf curl v3/apps` gives apps across all orgs, but,  Can you share the exact syntax of `cf login`,  because we login with specific Org and space as option... so,how PCF allows cf cli user to get the details of app across all users? Hope you understand my question

Comment: You login to specific org and space for convenience purposes, you don't really have to target any org or any space. Saying that, there is no relation between targeted org/space and apps you running curl command. The result you receive is contains only apps which belongs to spaces and orgs which your user has permissions assigned.

Comment: Is this a JSON output? `cf curl "v3/apps"`